24.04 Fresh Install "Invalid Partition Table"at Startup
Fresh Ubuntu install, get invalid partition Table at start. If I press enter, or F2, Ubuntu starts O K. Boot option list= Legacy,Advanced Boot Options= Enable Legacy Option ROMS, is enabled. Secure boot off. SSD is MBR. Any thoughts? Dell Latitude E6540

From live install post these: sudo parted -l & lsblk -f

I created a bug about this: https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/ubiquity/+bug/2091233

I fixed my Dell E6540 boot error msg "invalid partition table." I've been sorting through partition table options which for me is bewildering. But I have another 6540 that boots correctly with no error. So I fdisk the table on the good one and used fdisk to setup an identical partition table on the one that was giving me the error msg. The good one looked like this:
$sudo fdisk -l
Device     Boot   Start       End   Sectors   Size Id Type
/dev/sda1  *       2048   1050623   1048576   512M ef EFI (FAT-12/16/32)
/dev/sda2       1052670 976771071 975718402 465.3G  5 Extended
/dev/sda5       1052672 976771071 975718400 465.3G 83 Linux
(loops deleted)
Dell E6540 boot: Legacy secure boot off. Booted the Ubuntu Server 24.04 installation USB stick, then exited to a terminal. Using fdisk /dev/sda, deleted the existing partitions then created a new partition table like the one above. Then formatted: sudo mkfs.fat -F32 /dev/sda1, then sudo mkfs.ext4 /dev/sda5. Rebooted to the Ubuntu 24.04 installation usb stick, restarted the Ubuntu Server 24.04 installation using my "custom" partition table. Finished the installation, rebooted, and it booted correctly with no error msg.

I fixed it on a 6540 by manually creating the partition table using a known good boot drive as my example. I am not a partition table whizkid, but believe Ubuntu is creating a partition table that is incompatible with the 6540. If you see my first answer above, I gave an example of a partition table that I know works. When I manually created that partition table using fdisk, then proceeded with the 24.04 installation using my table instead of a ubuntu created table, boot problem solved.
